# Where can I see the Synonym Maps that have been declared?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I have declared a synonym map in my azure search service and mapped it to one of the indices through code ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-synonyms-tutorial-sdk#sample-code)). But when I want to see what I have declared through my portal I don't seem to have any provision. Is there any way where I can see the synonyms that have been declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the portal does not allow you to view the synonyms, however you can make an API call to get this information. Here is more information on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/get-synonym-map

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list api to see all of your synonyms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/list-synonym-maps

To see mapping of the synonyms maps to index fields, you can use a select clause like "$select=name,fields/name,fields/synonymMaps" with the list index api:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/list-indexes#examples